# comparing the two values line by line from two different text files

Tags: sql, linux, shell

i have two text files i want to compare the data between the two text files line by line and i have to maintain the matched values in to one file and unmatched values in to another file.
i am giving the examples

```
a.txt
10
20
30
```

the values in the a.txt are appending horizontally.

```
b.txt
10
30
20
```

the values in the b.txt are appending vertically

can u help me to write a shell script for comparing the above two text files line by line.if the line is matched i have to send the output to the one line else it has to send the out put to the another file.

i/o is 10 only.(line with possition comparission).

Comment: To compare file content in shell scripting there is a command you have to check and if you really want to learn shell scripting then try to read book by steve parker shell receipe I think so name of the book but writer name I am sure.

Comment: Please show the files, your description is not clear. Also, show exactly what output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
paste a.txt b.txt | sed -n '/\([0-9]\+\)[[:space:]]\+\1/p' > c.txt
```

`c.txt` will contain:

```
10 10
```

And

```
paste a.txt b.txt | sed '/\([0-9]\+\)[[:space:]]\+\1/d' > d.txt
```

`d.txt` will contain:

```
20 30
30 20
```